# blender model posing randomly

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, pose-mode, z-fighting

currently, im workin on an animation, and for some reason whenever i try to do a pose, the limbs that i posed will snap to a random spot. I have tried applying the rest pose as the default pose, but alas, it still snaps to a random spot in the scene, like in the pic shown below. I was wondering if you all could help me out as to what could be making this type of bug?

[image: random pose]

Comment: Do you mean that the controller bones snap? maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: heres the google drive link to my file. you can try to move the hands of the character on the right to understand what i really mean. I have tried a lot of different solutions but to no avail  
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vr_gnvS_aXnYaE3ZlHlbIcAUaCCAbJLr?usp=share_link